# Virtual folder data for your Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone, directory, virtual

i am thinking to extend my app for Windows Phone (7) with new features like data tranfer to pc.
My app can download mp3's in app's isolated storage, so i need a way for user to be able to move theese mp3's directly on his computer.

The best scenario will be:
When user connect his phone on computer, a folder (as usb disk) will apear with specific content inside (the mp3s)!

Maybe this way is in readonly mode, i dont carem, but is possible?
If not possible other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No This is not possible. App storage is kept separate from the file system you can access with the explorer.

maybe the easiest way is to transfer data to the cloud somewhere and let users download the data from the clould instead of by connecting the phone to your pc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, basically i am thinking a more confusing way! Maybe if when my app is open and connect the cable to pc i will create a virtual folder and i copy the file streams to that folder! This can been done somehow?